# How to skew element but keep text normal (unskewed)

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is it possible to reproduce this image using only CSS?

[image]

I want to apply this to my menu, so the brown background appears on `hover` instance

I don't know how to do this, I only have;

```
.menu li a:hover{
     display:block;
     background:#1a0000;
     padding:6px 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

`skew` a parent element (`li` in this example) and **inverse skew** its child elements:

[image: CSS Menu skewed buttons diagonal borders]

```css
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transform: skew(20deg); /* SKEW */
}

nav li a {
  display: block; /* block or inline-block is needed */
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font: 30px/1 sans-serif;
  transform: skew(-20deg); /* UNSKEW */
  color: inherit;
}

nav li.active,
nav li:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: yeah... and thanks too to Reformulate my question.. i don't remember that `skew` name.. :)

Comment: this: `display:inline-block;` don't work IE8 or less... so i put some `*float:left;` hack to make this "inline" on IE. But when i mouse over the menu, (on IE8) i can't setup some normal background (without the skew). Any tips?

Comment: @Preston sure, use images and help us kill IE8

Comment: That only works if you have an element nested inside, I'd like to just effect the text.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard you cannot; so wrap your text into a `<span>` and do the same.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan <--- what he said. Please.... nobody ever do this in practice... just wrap it in a span and give it those same skew properties and maybe a `display: inline-block` or something.

Comment: I could not revert the skew of a `span` child. Had to use a `div` instead. Possibly something to do with the `display` property though, not sure.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a fiddle for use across different browsers - I created in a couple of minutes.

Try playing with the arguments, I used `:before` and `:after` to do this.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTBAE/

Comment: Any chance you could explain this? I'm kinda at a loss for what it's doing and would like to learn a bit about `:before` and `:after`

Comment: I would have gone for the transform method as well, but this has better browser support!

Comment: While this is almost Xbrowser (:after, :before) you can only get an angle of 45°

Comment: You can adjust the border-widths to change the slope. http://jsfiddle.net/DTBAE/1/

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `transform: skew(X, Y)` property to achieve this. Creating a skewed outer container, then skew the opposite amount on an inner container to skew the text back to being straight. See this fiddle for example;

http://jsfiddle.net/UZ6HL/4/

From what you have said, I *believe* this is what you want, if not please clarify when the item should display the background.

Answer (score 5):

```css
.skew {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  transform: skewX(-7deg);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.skew p {
  transform: skewX(7deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="skew">
  <p>This is caption</p>
</div>
```

Here's [an example](http://vizua.net/skewed-div-with-normal-text)

Answer (score 2):

To have IE support just add `-ms-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);` beside all the other `transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clip-path` to make results like these.
For example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0 10px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can [**generate your clip**](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) from here and use it in your code.

Here is a working [Fiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/yL2dv8hw/)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: SPAN is NOT affected by transform CSS functionality, so you will need a DIV or change span to display: block; otherwise they will NOT be affected.

So just put the TEXT inside a separate div and unskew it.

example wrapper div is:

```
 transform: skewx(35deg)
```

but text div is:

```
transform: skewx(-35deg);
```

here is codepen: https://codepen.io/dmitrisan/pen/NWaYEzV