# Skew Bootstrap Nav List Item and Keep Link Straight

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, skew

I'm trying to skew the bootstrap nav li using CSS `transform` and I can achieve that, but when I try to reverse the skew on the link within, the li skew is also reversed back. I don't know why. I tried doing what is mentioned in the accepted answer here: [How to skew element but keep text normal (unskewed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947565/how-to-skew-element-but-keep-text-normal-unskewed)

However, while it seems to work with that  code, it does not with the bootstrap nav ul li.

See issue (Ignore this): http://jsfiddle.net/dfqzkqL5/

Corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/dfqzkqL5/3/

```css
.skew li {
  display:inline-block;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.noskew {
     display:inline-block;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav skew">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="noskew">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="noskew">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded=" class="skew"false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="noskew">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="noskew">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="noskew">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="noskew">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="noskew">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I'm just trying to achieve that with the bootstrap navbar. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your original skew is being applied twice because your CSS rule `skew li` matches the `li` in the outer list as well as the one in the inner list. To fix that, use the CSS `skew > li` instead, so the skew only gets applied to the outer list. When the skew is being applied only once, the reverse skew will work properly.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Fixed JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dfqzkqL5/2/

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, both the li and the text are skewed. What's different?

Comment: @Chris What browser are you using? I just updated the fiddle to fix the order of the transform rules, so that may fix it. I've also added a screenshot to my answer that shows what it looks like to me.

Comment: @Chris Perhaps you mean to add the `noskew` class to the links inside your header?

Comment: Updated the question with corrected jsfiddle (I had goofed in the html) and I updated the code in the snippet here in the question. Please see the updated. Using updated Firefox. And while I see the subnav is doing what is expected, the main nav items are not.