# FullCalendar Scheduler : Parallelogram Shaped Events

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

I would like to change the event shape from a square to a parallelogram, see image below for an example:

[image]

I tried changing the CSS

```html
.fc-event-container{
   background-color:rgba(2,2,2,0.9);
   float:left;
    Skew 
   -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg); 
   -moz-transform: skew(-60deg); 
   -o-transform: skew(-60deg);
   transform: skew(-60deg);
}
```

But it distorted the event container, see image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using info from here [How to skew element but keep text normal (unskewed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947565/how-to-skew-element-but-keep-text-normal-unskewed)

```
.fc-content {
  Skew -webkit-transform: skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: skew(60deg);
  transform: skew(60deg);
}
```

Seems to work

https://jsfiddle.net/qjLs3tfa/

The float: left may cause it to shrink the event though as seen in month view in fiddle