# The content inside skew component is overflowed when the content has long text

Tags: html, css, transform, transition, skew

I'm creating a component using skew transform (for making shape). In order to make the text inside skew is unskewed, I use the reverted **deg** value
However I'm facing with the problem that: when the text is too long, it's gonna be overflow (outside of the box)
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1onG.png)

I've tried with padding, margin and some other ways but still no luck.
Do you guys have idea any about this? Many thanks

Link demo:

```css
.container{
    transform: skew(-12deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-12deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-12deg, 0deg);
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
}

.inner{
    transform: skew(12deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(12deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(12deg, 0deg);
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
</div> </div>
```

Comment: Maybe this answer has the answer you're searching for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947565/how-to-skew-element-but-keep-text-normal-unskewed

Comment: Hi @Georgi Atanasov, thank for your reply. Unfortunately, I tried that link too but it doesn't relate to my issue :(