# Skewed Borders on a Div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, skew

I'm trying to skew a div, similar to this:
[Slant the top of a div using css without skewing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591584/slant-the-top-of-a-div-using-css-without-skewing-text)
or this: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/21/slopy-elements-with-css3/

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image: funky bordered boxes]

Basically, I need to slant the borders in weird ways on **all 4 sides**. I can do this with background images, but I'd prefer some way to do this in CSS so the divs can be responsive in width and height. I'd like to find a solution that works on older browsers, but I understand I can't have everything!

What would be the best way to have slanted borders on all 4 sides? (Note: the border on the bottom of the green box slants up in the middle, and down on the outside, and I do NOT need the borders to do this. just a slant in one direction is good.)

Comment: Interesting question.. I don't know whether I should use `rotate` or `skew`

Comment: I'm very interested in this one -- good question

Comment: You could skew the div one way and skew the text backwards the same amount..

Comment: @Paulie_D That would only work if they were not irregular. I don't want a parallelogram, but an irregular trapezoid.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52455594/8620333

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was able to make something *very similar*.. it works in all modern browsers.

[image]

**HTML** - Pretty simple

```css
div:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgb(122, 206, 122);
  height: 140px;
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(2deg);
}

div:nth-child(1) p {
  transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(10deg) rotate(-2deg);
  padding: 3% 2%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 180px solid rgb(233, 233, 65);
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
}

div:nth-child(2) p {
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  padding: 3.5% 3%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  border-top: 140px solid rgb(253, 74, 74);
  border-left: 23px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
}

div:nth-child(3) p {
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -140px;
  padding: 3% 3%;
}

div:nth-child(3):before {
  content: '';
  width: 124%;
  height: 80px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20%;
  bottom: 120px;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>text..</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>text..</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>text..</p>
</div>
```

[**Full Screen Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/53FrA/embedded/result/) ---- [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/53FrA/)

Comment: This works pretty nicely. The green box works GREAT, but the yellow and red both have a lot of trouble at small sizes. Like this: http://s16.postimg.org/42gvtkggl/Capture.png

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use "clip-path" and set any shape you needed. 
P.S. JS is only for transforming every 2 seconds.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var textBlock = document.querySelector(".text-block");

function gRI(max) { // getRandomInt
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

setInterval(function(){

 // new color
  
  let newColor = "rgb(" + gRI(255) + "," + gRI(255) + "," + gRI(255) +")";
 
 wrapper.style["background-color"] = newColor;
  
  // new shape
  
  let newShape = 
  "polygon(" +
  gRI(40) + "px " + gRI(40) + "px, " + // top left
 gRI(40) + "px " + "calc(100% - " + gRI(40) + "px), " +  // top right
  "calc(100% - " + gRI(40) + "px) " + "calc(100% - " + gRI(40) + "px), " +
  "calc(100% - " + gRI(40) + "px) " + gRI(40) + "px " +
  ")";
  
  textBlock.innerHTML = "clip-path: " + newShape +
             " <br><br> background-color: " + newColor;
  
  wrapper.style["clip-path"] = newShape;
}, 2000)
```

```css
.wrapper{
  box-sizing: border-box;

  width: 90%;
  min-width: 200px;
  
  margin: 25px auto;
  padding: 50px;
  
  background-color: lightgray;
  
  transition: 0.5s;
  
  clip-path: polygon( 25px 25px, 25px calc(100% - 25px), calc(100% - 25px) calc(100% - 25px), calc(100% - 25px) 25px );
}

.text-block{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-block">Changes every 2 seconds...</div>
</div>
```