# How to make a paragraph fit inside a skewed parent div without getting skewing value?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create this using HTML/CSS...
http://postimg.org/image/uhmhf04qz/

Now, Initially I tried..

```
    <div class='box'>
    <p>paragraph here</p>
    </div>
```

css:

```
    .box {
    background: red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    }
```

But that also applies skew to the child paragraph, Which makes it look pretty deformed, I'm trying to make the paragraph fit in the boundaries of the parent div but without being skewed too, Is there a way to do that in HTML/CSS?

Comment: See this answer I wrote a few days ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147241/skewed-borders-on-a-div/19147455#19147455 .. It is semi-responsive, and works relevantly well..

Answer (score 0):

Compensate with a negative value for the positive value within the p element.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4NtT/4/

```
<div id='shape'>
    <p>paragraph here</p>
</div>

#shape {
    width: 450px;
    height: 350px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(2d0eg);
    background: #333;
    margin:100px;
}
#shape p {
    font:1em normal Futura, sans-serif;
    color:#f1f1f1;
    padding:60px 60px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg) !important;
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg) !important;
    transform: skew(-20deg) !important;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid the !important in your css at all costs. Btw, try to make the content longer and you'll see the paragraph doesn't notice the bounderies of the srewed div.

Comment: @blake yeah, but this makes the text escape the parent div boundaries.

Comment: You can adjust that with padding.

Comment: Here's a much larger shape with a large body of paragraph text.http://jsfiddle.net/u4NtT/5/