# How to create an irregular square shape in css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Looking for the code to make this particular shape with CSS..

Any help much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

> The `clip-path` CSS property creates a clipping region that defines
>   what part of an element should be displayed. More specifically, those
>   portions that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are
>   hidden.

Try this code snippet.

```css
div{
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 7%, 91% 14%, 98% 91%, 0% 100%);
   clip-path: polygon(5% 7%, 91% 14%, 98% 91%, 0% 100%);
   background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Browser support is still quite limited though https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with some rotation and perspective:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #f540a8;
  margin: 20px;
  transform: perspective(180px) rotateX(15deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Or using SVG:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width=200>
  <polygon points="20,0 150,20 170,130 0,150" fill="#f540a8" /> 
</svg>
```

And also using gradient (but without transparency):

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 46%,#fff 50%) right/10px 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 46%,#fff 50%) top/100% 10px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 46%,#fff 50%) bottom/100% 10px,
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 46%,#fff 50%) left/10px 100%, 
    #f540a8;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
clip-path: polygon(30px 0 , 250px 0, 200px 300px, 0 0);
```

Please see the example here: https://codepen.io/shakogele/pen/ZMZGGK