# Can this skewed box be created in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a series of distorted boxes/divs on a website. All of them will be distorted differently.  Current plan is to simply use the images as DIV background images and lay text on top, but I was hoping there might be a CSS solution to this.

Note that this isn't just a square box with perspective - each side is different length.

[image: Black Box]

Comment: From my point of view using `translate` and playing with the perspective is the best way

Comment: add radius to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52455695/8620333