# how to create this type of shape with text inside it?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating this type of shape with text inside it. but it doesn' work, can anyone help me?

[image]

i have tried this code :

```css
.diagonal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  margin: 10px;
  /* Zentriert den Inhalt */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.diagonal>span {
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="diagonal"><span>Diagonal</span></div>
```

Comment: i have tried this link to make like that shape but not found https://codepen.io/Minilexikon/pen/yVRdQY

Comment: Have a look here : https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/ this may get you close to what you are looking for.  then you can add a     .text {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 200px;
     position: absolute;
     top: -7px;
     left: 131px;
     z-index: 1;
     color: white;
    }
 to place your text inside the quadrilateral

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52455594/8620333

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clip-path property to achieve this and placing all the component accordingly

here is one site to generate clip-path 
[clip path generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)