# CSS custom shape with irregular rectangle and border

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a button like this:

[image]

After researching online, I only came up with making a parallelogram. But this is the result:

[image]

Code:

```css
.parallelogram {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid #EC00F4;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #EC00F4;
}
```

```html
<button class="parallelogram"> Hello button </button>
```

Is there a way to make the edges go where I want (like in the picture) but without moving the text ?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52455695/8620333

Comment: The text is straight... I that on purpose? It looks awkward -being part of a highly expressive 3Dish parent...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Very close but this is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/zn5oj8bh/ .The borders don't work.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, the text must be straight. It's a button.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan we should not apply the 3D to the parent but apply it to a pseudo element that you place behind

Comment: @temani Yes. But from any perspective as a designer it looks strangely awkward... It was just a question/comment just to double-check. Thank you for the comment though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use clip-path on pseudo elements. The trick is to consider the same clip-path and apply a scale transformation to one pseudo element to simulate the border. Simply adjust the value of the polygon to get the needed result.

Hover to see a different clip-path:

```css
.parallelogram {
   padding:20px 45px;
   font-size:30px;
   color: white;
   border:none;
   background:none;
   outline:none;
   position:relative;
   z-index:0;
   margin:15px;
   filter:drop-shadow(0px 30px 25px rgba(236, 0, 244, 0.45));
}
.parallelogram:before,
.parallelogram:after {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   z-index:-1;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   clip-path: polygon(0 11%, 100% 0, 90% 88%, 3% 96%);
   transition:1s all;
   background:#000;
}
.parallelogram:before {
  background:#EC00F4;
  transform:scale(1.05,1.12);
}

.parallelogram:hover:before,
.parallelogram:hover:after {
   clip-path: polygon(5% 2%, 100% 5%, 100% 100%, 0% 94%);
}
```

```html
<button class="parallelogram"> Hello button </button>
<button class="parallelogram"> button </button>
<button class="parallelogram"> A </button>
```

You can also consider pixel value to keep the same shape whataver the content inside:

```css
.parallelogram {
   padding:20px 45px;
   font-size:30px;
   color: white;
   border:none;
   background:none;
   outline:none;
   position:relative;
   z-index:0;
   margin:15px;
   filter:drop-shadow(0px 30px 25px rgba(236, 0, 244, 0.45));
}
.parallelogram:before,
.parallelogram:after {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   z-index:-1;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   clip-path: polygon(0 10px, 100% 0, calc(100% - 8px) calc(100% - 15px), 5px calc(100% - 8px));
   transition:1s all;
   background:#000;
}
.parallelogram:before {
  background:#EC00F4;
  transform:scale(1.05,1.12);
}

.parallelogram:hover:before,
.parallelogram:hover:after {
   clip-path: polygon(0 5px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 10px calc(100% - 20px));
}
```

```html
<button class="parallelogram"> Hello button </button>
<button class="parallelogram"> button </button>
<button class="parallelogram"> A </button>
```

Comment: This is amazing. This is exactly like in the picture! Amazing job @Temani Afif

Comment: This will not work in IE11. Not that I personally care, just saying...

Answer (score 1):

This works kinda like you want it:

```css
button{
   width: 150px;
   height: 50px;
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 20%, 92% 14%, 88% 88%, 0% 100%);
   clip-path: polygon(0% 20%, 92% 14%, 88% 88%, 0% 100%);
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="parallelogram"> Hello button </button>
```

**EDIT:**

You can create an SVG that looks exactly like your button here: https://vectr.com/new

You can add border + shadow and simply copy the html.

Comment: Very close: https://jsfiddle.net/zn5oj8bh/1/ 
But the border doesn't work and the box-shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pseudo element to set your perspective effect:

example

```css
.parallelogram {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  /* appearance:none; could be used too */
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;  /* show where and that i'm clickable */
}

.parallelogram:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 110%;  /* might need to be resized */
  height: 100%;
  transform: /* tune the rotation and perspective values to your needs */
    perspective(200px) 
    rotatey(35deg) 
    rotatex(-25deg)
    ;
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid #ec00f4;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #ec00f4;
}
```

```html
<button class="parallelogram"> Hello button </button>
```

screenshot from firefox : [image]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ?? it's there , which browser do you use ? *(made and added a screenshot from latest of today Firefox)*

Comment: This is very good and close @G-Cyr, but Temani made a better version. Thank you again so much !

Comment: @IkePr that was an hint :) . have fun playing with CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Add a span, with the class .unskew and do the opposite of your skew effect on the background and change the display rule.

**Example:**

**CSS**

```
.parallelogram {
    transition: background 0.3s;
    transform: skew(-25deg);
    /* SKEW */
}

.unskew{
    display: block;
    /* block or inline-block is needed */
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font: 30px/1 sans-serif;
    transform: skew(25deg);
    /* UNSKEW */
    color: inherit;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="parallelogram"><span class="unskew" >Hello button</span></button>
```