# Custom button without SVG

Tags: html, css, material-ui, frontend, next.js

I was trying to do a button with and I have tried in different ways. svg worked but unfortunately SVG is not supporting on Next.js & Material UI. I am providing the code and the screenshot below.

Any kind of help would be really helpful

[image]

```css
span.button__publish {
    margin-left: 45px;
    position: relative;
}

.button__publish button {
    width: 137px;
    height: 37.3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #8ae38c;
}
```

```html
*emphasized text*
<span class="button__publish">
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text publish MuiButton-textPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button">
   <span class="MuiButton-label">Publish</span>
  </button>
</span>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52455695/8620333

Comment: if SVG works use it as a CSS background

Comment: Thanks @FabrizioCalderan that's a really good option

Answer (score 0):

You can use css's `clip-path` property. I added an example, but you have to find out the exact values yourself so that it looks like you want. For reference see [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

```css
span.button__publish {
    margin-left: 45px;
    position: relative;
}

.button__publish button {
    width: 137px;
    height: 37.3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #8ae38c;
    clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 75% 75%, 75% 100%, 50% 75%, 0% 75%);
}
```

```html
*emphasized text*
<span class="button__publish">
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text publish MuiButton-textPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button">
   <span class="MuiButton-label">Publish</span>
  </button>
</span>
```

EDIT:
this way part of the border is "eaten", too, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style) for how to  fix this.