# How to have a crooked div?

Tags: html, css

How to have a crooked div like the red div in [this page](http://www.spyk.ru/)

Here's my CSS:

```
#parallelogram {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    background: red;
}
```

but it's not correct, i think

Comment: What makes you think it's not correct? Can you provide a working example to illustrate your problem(s)?

Comment: Could you please specify what is "not correct"? It's hard to help otherwise...

Comment: This might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591584/slant-the-top-of-a-div-using-css-without-skewing-text

Comment: It is `skewY(20deg)` not `skew(20deg)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess (and with the poor information provided it's really just a guess) it might not be working because you are only using the vendor-prefixed versions of transform. The browser you're using might be already (and only) supporting the prefix-less form, so you need to add it:

```
-webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
   -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
     -o-transform: skew(20deg);
        transform: skew(20deg);
```

Oh, and if you're trying to copy the exact skew of the example you provided, only along the Y axis, use `skewY()` instead of `skew()` and 10 degrees instead of 20 degrees:

```
-webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
   -moz-transform: skewY(10deg);
     -o-transform: skewY(10deg);
        transform: skewY(10deg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon quick inspecting I found that div's transform properties as follows:

```
transform: skewY(10deg);
```

Here is a fiddle to get you started

http://jsfiddle.net/98c7e0mq/